# Why would an Azure web site restart multiple times after publishing to a deployment slot and auto-swapping to production slot?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots

I publish my (pre-compiled) ASP.NET web forms site from Visual Studio to a deployment slot with auto swap enabled so that it'll swap over into my production slot. It works; the production slot eventually gets the new code and it's fine but it doesn't deploy warm. There are maybe 10-15 seconds where the site is unresponsive. After debugging further (by using application initialization to try to do some warming up and also log the restart) I found that the site is actually getting restarted a couple times during the swap - and I'm guessing at least once AFTER the swap. The newly published code gets restarted 3 times and the old code gets restarted twice. None of the application settings are "slot settings" so I'm not sure what is forcing them both to restart multiple times.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. See [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-site-swaps) for what's supposed to happen.